# Electron can't seem to find my function when using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

## The problem

I'm creating an app for live chatting as a project for my exam. Everything has been working great up until now. For some reason electron isn't able to find functions even though the functions clearly are in my code.

## The code

```
/*
  * login()
  */

 async function login() {

   var userName = document.getElementsByName("userName");
   var password = document.getElementsByName("password");

   if(validateForm('login')) {
     var sql     = "SELECT * FROM db.users WHERE ?? = ?";
     var inserts = ["userName", userName];
     sql         = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

     connResult = await conn(sql);

     var dbUsername;
     var dbPassword;
     var autologin;

     if(connResult === 'resolved') {
       dbUserName = result[0]["userName"];
       dbPassword = result[0]["password"];
     } else {
       console.log(connResult);
     }

     if(document.getElementsByName("autoLogin").checked) {
       autoLogin = true;
     } else {
       autoLogin = false;
     }

     if(verifyUser(userName, password, dbUserName, dbPassword)) {
       storeUser(connResult, autoLogin);
       if(await fetchUserData(userName)) {
         mainProcess.createMain();

         window = remote.getCurrentWindow

         window.close();
       }
     }
   }
 };

 /*
  * verifyUser()
  */

 function verifyUser(userName, password, dbUserName, dbPassword) {

   if(compare(dbUserName, userName)){
     console.log("UserName exists");

     if(compare(dbPassword, password)) {
       console.log("password exists");
       return true;

     } else {
       console.log("Wrong password");
       document.getElementById("formWarning").innerHTML
       return false;

     }
   } else {
     console.log("userName doesn't exist");
     return false;

   }
 };
```

Here's the HTML:

`<button id="loginButton" onclick="login()" class="buttonMedium">Login</button>`

I'm getting the following error when running the function `login()` via onclick:

"Uncaught TypeError: login is not a function"

And when i type `login()` into my dev console:

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'placeholder' of undefined"

I also get the last error because the documents can't "communicate". It is trying to access a form in my html and it can't read the placeholder for some reason.

As i mentioned everything worked before. I have no idea where this went wrong. Hope that you guys can help me.

Comment: remove the `async` before the login function

Comment: @Marc but i need it for the "await" in the function

Comment: You should enable the nodeintegration first check the below linke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482559/cant-connect-to-nedb-on-render-process-electron/60482768#60482768

Answer (score 0):

Requiring a script means it has it's own context. Asuming your code is in a script required at the bottom of your html file:

```
<script>
      require('./index.js')
</script>
```

Assing the function to the button like this:

```
document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', login);
```

After that remember you also don't need the "onclick" property on your HTML:

```
<button id="loginButton" class="buttonMedium">Login</button>
```

Comment: I tried this. And now i'm just getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". It's like the JS can't read the HTML properly.

Comment: I just realized that i'm also getting some errors in the console log of the main process: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not instantiate: ProductRegistryImpl.Registry", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (108)

Comment: I'm not sure the second error is not related to your debug tools. Can you post how are you linking the javascript code to the HTML?

Comment: I'm linking the JS in the top of the HTML head <script src="index.js"></script>

Comment: Try linking it at the bottom of your document. After the HTML tags that you are trying to access so it will be loaded after them.

Comment: @MadsAhlquistJensen That second error you quoted, has nothing to do with your application and does not affect its operation. I get it all the time in Electron too, it is a fault in the Developer Tools bubbling up.