# Can't connect to NeDB on render process Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, nedb

I have problem with connect NeDB to my react-electron app. Now I install NeDB on my project and connect him to `electron.js` file.

```
const Datastore = require('nedb');
let db = {};
db.students = new Datastore({
    filename:'./students.json',
    autoload: true
})
db.students.insert({name : "Putin V.V.", year: 1952});
```

Now I need connect this db to my app.js file.
**How I can manipulate with this file on render part?**

[GitHub code](https://github.com/YaroslavWeb/Tester-students)

Comment: File "students.json" creates *.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your specific problem by explaining how your app and code are setup more or by providing more source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your idea by using ipc at Electron.
I posted an answer before. Please check the below.

[how to communicate between react and electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681069/how-to-communicate-between-react-and-electron/59681218#59681218)

But here is the pre-requirements.

You should enable the nodeintegration when you are creating the `BrowserWindow`
So at your code, it should be like this

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        minWidth: 900,
        minHeight: 600,
        show: false,
        icon: "",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
```

After this, you can use this ipcRenderer at renderer(your react app).
If you don't set this option. Then you will face the similar issue as below

[ipcRenderer not receiving message from main process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227586/ipcrenderer-not-receiving-message-from-main-process/60227981#60227981)

Comment: thx! I see your github repo before and use global object "global.database = db;". And now it's working!